# GGplot2: removing parts from panel (facet_wrap)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to modify the part I marked in the image below. It's the gray part that I am talking about. If possible I would like to remove it or make it smaller, depending on how both results will look. This way I will have more space to perhaps add an extra row of plots. My code is below the image.
[image]

```
spaghetti_plot_multiple <- function(input, MV, item_level){
  MV <- enquo(MV)
  titles <- enquo(item_level)
  input %>% 
    filter(!!(MV) == item_level) %>% 
    mutate(first_answer = first_answer) %>%
    ggplot(.,aes( x = time, y = jitter(Answer), group = ID)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = factor(first_answer))) +
    labs(title = titles ,x = 'Time', y = 'Answer', colour = 'Answer time 0') +
    facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_x")+ 
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 8),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20,
                                face = 'bold', color = 'black')) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("1" = "cyan", "2" = "black", 
                               "3" = "#ff7f00", "4" = "blue", '5' = "#e41a1c"))
}
```

Comment: Do you need to remove only the first two strips above or all the strips ?

Comment: All of them. And if possible an alternative to only make them smaller. Would like to see how both solutions would look.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your question has helped me finding the answer. I used: `strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment of Marco Sandri, the following removes the gray parts as well as the text. Within `theme()` you must add: `strip.background = element_blank(),
strip.text.x = element_blank()`. So the full code becomes (line 11 and 12):

```
spaghetti_plot_multiple <- function(input, MV, item_level){
  MV <- enquo(MV)
  titles <- enquo(item_level)
  input %>% 
  filter(!!(MV) == item_level) %>% 
  mutate(first_answer = first_answer) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes( x = time, y = jitter(Answer), group = ID)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(first_answer))) +
  labs(title = titles ,x = 'Time', y = 'Answer', colour = 'Answer time 0') +
  facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_x")+ 
  theme( strip.background = element_blank(),
      strip.text.x = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20,
                                face = 'bold', color = 'black')) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("1" = "green", "2" = "black", 
                               "3" = "#ff7f00", "4" = "blue", '5' = "#e41a1c"))
}
```